# Why my google map not show in div

Tags: jquery, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, twitter-bootstrap-3

I use google map for contact page but map not showing in div box .
please tell me why not show .

```
[https://plnkr.co/edit/irmYNKsv0yH2GVx1kcur?p=preview][1]
```

Comment: Have you actually checked the console.log errors at all? 
Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined(…)

Comment: how can i fix it ?

Comment: If google hasn't been defined it would suggest either the map script you are pulling in is outdated, or it could be to do with the fact that you are pulling in the resource over http from a https page. Either way, the problem lies with the JavaScript file you are pulling in, or the way you are using it.

Comment: Just tested it in your plnkr, update the map src to https, it works. https://plnkr.co/edit/l03HPHM97oaBb2nHxEQZ?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are requesting the Google Map resource over HTTP from a HTTPS page.
Update the map resource request to HTTPS and it should work.

https://plnkr.co/edit/l03HPHM97oaBb2nHxEQZ?p=preview

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```